# Creating resulting table from three tables which use id or uuid

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have one database [mariadb](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/more-advanced-joins/) 10.7 with name `grocery`. There are 3 tables

- grocery.goods
- grocery.shop
- grocery.suppliers

The tables use the primary key sometimes id, sometimes uuid. Old data use id, new data uuid. It's not my decision, it's set up in the company where I work.
It is not possible to add new columns to the tables.

[UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) example: "123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000".
In this question is used only part of uuid for example "ab".

Table grocery.goods:

```
┌───────┬─────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ id_gd │ uuid_gd │ id_sh    │ uuid_sh  │ from_country │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ 7     │  null   │ null     │ ab       │ Brazil       │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ null  │  gn     │ null     │ ab       │ Mexico       │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ null  │  gp     │ 3        │ null     │ Paraguay     │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ 9     │  null   │ 3        │ null     │ Ecuador      │
└───────┴─────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

Table grocery.shop:

```
┌───────┬─────────┬────────────┐
│ id_sh │ uuid_sh │ item       │
├───────┼─────────┼────────────┤
│ null  │ ab      │ pineapples │
├───────┼─────────┼────────────┤
│ 3     │ null    │ bananas    │
└───────┴─────────┴────────────┘
```

Table grocery.suppliers:

```
┌───────┬─────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────────┐
│ id_sp │ uuid_sp │ id_sh    │ uuid_sh  │ supp_company │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ 12    │ null    │ null     │ ab       │ company1     │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ null  │  sd     │ null     │ ab       │ company2     │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ null  │  sr     │ 3        │ null     │ company3     │
├───────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────────┤
│ 13    │  null   │ 3        │ null     │ company4     │
└───────┴─────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────────┘
```

================================================================

Resulting table:

```
┌──────────┬──────────┬────────────┬──────────────┬────────────────┐
│ id_sh    │ uuid_sh  │ item       │ from_country │ supp_company   │
├──────────┼──────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼────────────────┤
│ null     │ ab       │ pineapples │ Brazil       │ company1       │
├──────────┼──────────┼────────────┼──────────────┼────────────────┤
│ 3        │ null     │ bananas    │ Paraguay     │ company3       │
└──────────┴──────────┴────────────┴──────────────┴────────────────┘
```

It is basically just a table `grocery.shop` with added columns "from_country" from table `grocery.goods` and "supp_company" from table `grocery.suppliers`.
From table `grocery.goods` is needed choose only first row with pineapples and first row with bananas.
From table `grocery.suppliers` is the same, is needed choose only first row with pineapples and first row with bananas. From table grocery.shop is needed to choose all rows.
I tried to create this resulting table with this query, but the query does not return the correct result.

```
SELECT DISTINCT shop.id_sh, 
                shop.uuid_sh, 
                shop.item,
                goods.from_country, 
                suppliers.supp_company
FROM shop
LEFT JOIN goods
ON ((shop.id_sh IS NOT NULL AND shop.id_sh = goods.id_sh) OR 
   ((shop.uuid_sh IS NOT NULL AND shop.uuid_sh = goods.uuid_sh))
LEFT JOIN suppliers
ON ((shop.id_sh IS NOT NULL AND suppliers.id_sh = shop.id_sh) OR 
   (shop.uuid_sh IS NOT NULL AND suppliers.uuid_sh = shop.uuid_sh))
```

Is it possible create this resulting table?

Comment: I think you should put `xxx IS NOT NULL` first in each comparison, so it doesn't try to compare `NULL`.

Comment: Ok, I edited query. But I think that between comparison is AND, therefore these are equivalent conditions. Despite editing, the query does not return the correct result.